# Hardware calibrate xbox360

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I am triing to recover an xbox360 wireless controle.

It had its L stick in bad shape, so i de-soldered and re-soldered a new part. The issue is, its "zero position" isn't zero.

[image]

If i move the the axis and let go, it always come back to that place...
I think is something with the potentiometer calibration.... is there any way to fix it?